# How to add 'lb' in siunitx and show variable instead of constant

Tags: siunitx

I have this simple water tank and I want to write at the rate in:

> r gal/min

> 1/4 lb/gal

(the problem is I cannot change constant at the `{}`, it has to be filled with constant, thus I trick it by using `$r$`  inside the second brackets)

(the second problem is there is no `\lb`, thus I use `\text{lb}`)

```
\usepackage{mathptmx} % To emulate your `font`
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write units correctly 
\usepackage{tikz} % Obvious
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} % To decorate the surface of water
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % The newer options for arrows (PGF 3.0)
\colorlet{water}{cyan!25} % Define color for the water
%--------------------------
% Dimensions of the tank
\def\tankwidth{6}
\def\tankheight{4}
\def\waterheight{2.2} % Water height 
%--------------------------
\tikzset{
    faucet/.pic={ % Define a 'pic' for the water inlet and outlet (PGF 3.0)
        \fill[water](-0.25,-0.25) rectangle (0.25,0.25);
        \draw[line width=1pt](-0.25,-0.25)--(0.25,-0.25) (-0.25,0.25)--(0.25,0.25);
    },
    myarrow/.tip={Stealth[scale=1.5]}, % Define a style for the tip of arrow
    surface water/.style= % style for border of water surface
    {decoration={random steps,segment length=1mm,amplitude=0.5mm}, decorate}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Water fill (I filled first so that way it is in the background)
    \fill[water] decorate[surface water]{(\tankwidth,\waterheight) -- (0,\waterheight)}--(0,0) -- (\tankwidth,0) -- cycle;
    
    % Tank
    \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) rectangle (\tankwidth,\tankheight);
    
    \coordinate (entrance) at (0,\tankheight-0.7);
    \coordinate (exit) at (\tankwidth,0.7);
    
    \pic[xshift=-2.5mm+0.5pt] at (entrance) {faucet}; % water inlet (0.5pt is half of line width) 
    \pic[xshift=2.5mm-0.5pt] at (exit) {faucet}; % outlet water
    
    % Entrance label (with `siunitx`)
    \node[align=right,left=1cm] (inlet-unit) at (entrance)  {\SI[per-mode=symbol]{6}{\liter\per\minute}\\\SI[per-mode=symbol]{0.1}{\kilogram\per\liter}};
    %[align=...] in the last node is necessary for splitting in two lines with `\\`
    \draw[-myarrow](inlet-unit)--([xshift=-5mm]entrance);
    
    % Exit label
    \node[align=left,right=1cm] (outlet-unit) at (exit) {\SI[per-mode=symbol]{5}{\liter\per\minute}};
    \draw[-myarrow]([xshift=5mm]exit)--(outlet-unit);
    
    \draw[|-|] ([xshift=-2mm]0,0) -- node[fill=white,inner xsep=0]{$V_{0}$}([xshift=-2mm]0,\waterheight); 
    
    % Fall water (i use `parabola` operation, it's more realistic, bacause it's a fall water) 
    \fill[water] ([shift={(0.5pt,-2.5mm)}]entrance) parabola (0.3*\tankwidth,1pt) -- 
    (0.5*\tankwidth,1pt) parabola[bend at end] ([shift={(0.5pt,2.5mm)}]entrance);
    
    % Inner labels
    \path (0.5*\tankwidth,\tankheight)--(0.5*\tankwidth,0)
    node[pos=0.2] {$x(t)$}
    node[pos=0.5] {?\,L}
    node[pos=0.8] {$x(0)=\SI{0}{\kilogram}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your example to a full minimal example and please only use what is relevant for your problem. All this tikz is clearly not relevant. The siunitx manual clearly explains how to define extra units.

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare your units
2. Use them as any other in your document.
3. Disable the parsing process of `siunitx` and use whatever you need in the argument to `\qty`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\lb}{lb}
\DeclareSIUnit{\gal}{gal}
\begin{document}
$\qty[parse-numbers=false, per-mode=symbol]{r}{\gal\per\minute}$

$\qty[parse-numbers=false, per-mode=fraction]{\frac{1}{4}}{\lb\per\gal}$
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]